# After redirect, how to display error messages coming from original file?

Tags: javascript, php, html, redirect

Here's what I'm trying to achieve: I want to redirect the user if any errors I check for are found to a html/php form (that the user see's first where inputs are previously created) with custom error messages.

Details: The User see's the HTML/PHP form first where they enter names in a csv format. After they click create, the names are processed in another file of just php where the names are checked for errors and other such things. If an error is found I want the User to be redirected to the HTML/PHP form where they can fix the errors and whatever corresponding error messages are displayed. Once they fix the names the User can click the 'create user' button and processed again (without errors hopefully) and upon completion, redirect user to a page where names and such things are displayed. The redirect happens after the headers are sent. From what I've read this isn't the best thing but, for now, it'll do for me.

Code For HTML/PHP form:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
    <head>
        <title>PHP FORM</title>
    </head> 
    <body>
<form method="post" action="processForm.php">

    Name: <input type="text" name="names" required = "required"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Create Users" onclick="formInputNames"><br>

    Activate: <input type="checkbox" name="activate">
</form>
<?php
// include 'processForm.php';
// errorCheck($fullname,$nameSplit,$formInputNames);
?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I tried messing around with 'include' but it doesn't seem to do anything, however, I kept it here to help illustrate what I'm trying to achieve.

Code For Process:

```
$formInputNames = $_POST['names'];

$active = (isset($_POST['activate'])) ? $_POST['activate'] : false;
//checks if activate checkbox is being used
$email = '@grabby.com';
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";

$fullnames = explode(", ", $_POST['names']);

if ($active == true) {
    $active = '1';
    //sets activate checkbox to '1' if it has been selected
}
/*----------------------Function to Insert User---------------------------*/
         A Function is here to place names and other fields in database.
/*-------------------------End Function to Insert User--------------------*/

/*-----------------------Function for Errors---------------------*/

function errorCheck($fullname,$nameSplit,$formInputNames){
    if ($formInputNames == empty($fullname)){
        echo 'Error: Name Missing Here: '.$fullname.'<br><br>';
        redirect('form.php');
    }
    elseif ($formInputNames == empty($nameSplit[0])) {
        echo 'Error: First Name Missing in: '.$fullname.'<br><br>';
        redirect('form.php');
    }
    elseif ($formInputNames == empty($nameSplit[1])) {
        echo 'Error: Last Name Missing in: '.$fullname.'<br><br>';
        redirect('form.php');
    }
    elseif (preg_match('/[^A-Za-z, ]/', $fullname)) {
        echo 'Error: Found Illegal Character in: '.$fullname.'<br><br>';
        redirect('form.php');
    }
}

/*-----------------------------End Function for Errors------------------------*/

/*--------------------------Function for Redirect-------------------------*/

function redirect($url){
    $string = '<script type="text/javascript">';
    $string .= 'window.location = "' .$url. '"';
    $string .= '</script>';

    echo $string;
}

/*-------------------------End Function for Redirect-----------------------*/

//  Connect to database
     I connect to the database here

foreach ($fullnames as $fullname) {
    $nameSplit = explode(" ", $fullname);

            //opens the database
I Open the database here

        errorCheck($fullname,$nameSplit,$formInputNames);

        $firstName = $nameSplit[0];//sets first part of name to first name
        $lastName = $nameSplit[1];//sets second part of name to last name
        $emailUser = $nameSplit[0].$email;//sets first part and adds email extension

        newUser($firstName,$lastName,$emailUser,$active,$conn);

        redirect('viewAll.php');
        //echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=viewAll.php">';
//if you try this code out, you can see my redirect to viewAll doesn't work when errors are found...I would appreciate help fixing this as well. My immediate fix is using the line under it but I don't like it.
}
```

Any help is certainly appreciated.Thank You

Also it's worth noting I'm new to php. I would like to have an answer in php as well (if possible).

Comment: Why the down vote? I think I did pretty well in providing detail as well as clarity. I did plenty of research on this topic and after a whole day, I couldn't find anything useful and that's why I'm here...

Answer (score 0):

There's multiple ways of doing so. I personally would use AJAX. On a 'form submit', run a javascript function calling an AJAX request to a .php file to check the form information, all using post method. Calculate all the `$_POST['variables']` checking for your defined errors. You would have an html element print the errors via AJAX request.

If there are 0 errors then in the request back return a string as so that your javascript function can look for if its ready to go. If ready to go, redirect the user to where ever you please.

AJAX is not hard and I only suggested the idea sense you put javascript in your tags.

**Another method:**
Having all your code on one .php file. When you submit the form to the same .php file check for the errors (at the top of the file). If $_POST['variables'] exist, which they do after you submit the form, you echo your errors in the needed places. If zero errors then you redirect the page.

Comment: thanks for the response, I'm not familiar with using AJAX but as per the multiple ways, can you provide another way?

Comment: I updated my answer with an alternative way. When I said there's multiple ways of doing so I meant more towards with ajax and methods of solving the issue. Similar to how people can all tell the same story and even though its a little bit different its still the same story. Ajax honestly is the more up to date answer and would make the rest of your website more dynamic and appealing. Re-directing multiple times for something that can be done with out the page re-directing or refreshing is redundant and in today's society, seen by many to be obsolete.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look into it.